# AccelerometerPlayActivity source transform

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'd like to transform this activity.

Que 1. one Ball Image -> variety of Ball Image
Que 2. Rect Collision -> Round Collision

---

```
        public void resolveCollisionWithBounds() {
            final float xmax = mHorizontalBound;
            final float ymax = mVerticalBound;
            final float x = mPosX;
            final float y = mPosY;
            if (x > xmax) {
                mPosX = xmax;
            } else if (x < -xmax) {
                mPosX = -xmax;
            }
            if (y > ymax) {
                mPosY = ymax;
            } else if (y < -ymax) {
                mPosY = -ymax;
            }
        }
```

---

```
    public SimulationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mXDpi = metrics.xdpi;
        mYDpi = metrics.ydpi;
        mMetersToPixelsX = mXDpi / 0.0254f;
        mMetersToPixelsY = mYDpi / 0.0254f;
        // rescale the ball so it's about 0.5 cm on screen
        Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
        final int dstWidth = (int) (sBallDiameter * mMetersToPixelsX + 0.5f);
        final int dstHeight = (int) (sBallDiameter * mMetersToPixelsY + 0.5f);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
        Options opts = new Options();
        opts.inDither = true;
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        mWood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wood, opts);        }
```